# Google Sheet script to automatically calculate a countdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I haven't coded in decades, and I'm looking for a way to automate my current "countdown" spreadsheet. I currently do things in an ugly, error-prone and roundabout way, a very small script should be able to make it much better.

**Goal:**

- Type in a duration in hours (typically, between 0 and 1,000) in a cell
- One cell below, get a running countdown of how many hours remain.

**Current situation:**

I've got the sheet set up to auto-recalc every hour, which is fine
then a 4-cells setup, repeated over multiple columns to track several timers:

- 1st cell (B2) is the input cell to type in the duration in hours
- 2nd cell (B3) is =now()+B2/24 , that calculates the expected date of completion resulting from B2
- 3rd cell (B4) contains a hard copy of B3's value so that recalcs don't change that "firm expected completion" date. I have to copy + pastevalue from B3 to B4 every time I modify B2, which is the main issue with that setup
- 4th cell (B5) is =(int(B4)-int(now()))*24+hour(B4)-hour(now()) and is the running countdown I watch out for. Had to use int() not day() otherwise I get bugs when the start and completion dates are not the same month.

**What I'd like:**

- To get rid of the 2 intermediate cells and the cumbersome + error-prone manual copy-pastevalue between them.
- An auto-trigger script that directly fills in B5 (actually, that would change to B3) with the countdown, using a formula that's probably
 (int(B2+$datetime_of_B2_modification) - int(now() )*24 + hour(B2+$datetime_of_B2_modification) - hour(now)). 
B2 is a direct reference to B2's value, $datetime_of_B2_modification is a value that is calculated each time I modify B2, and only then (not when the sheet is recalced, not when I hover over B2 but don't actually modify it) and is then harcoded into B5's formula; now() is gSheet's actual function that returns now's datetime.
- ideally, that autotrigger script automatically creates that formula one cell below the one were I enter the hours duration, ie I don't have to make a different script for every column in my spreadsheet, it creates the formula "one cell below", not at a fixed cell.

My decades-old skills are rusty, I've been struggling to get started but I'm going nowhere. If someone could magically whip up that script, I'd be very grateful !

Best regards, Olivier

Thinking of it, a script to automate the copy+pastevalue step w/o changing anything else would be a nice first step. Getting rid of the 2 extra rows isn't that critical, though it would be nice.

**Edit after 1st answer**: I thing I need something along the lines of what's below; ?? lines are lines I know are wrong

```
function onEdit(e)() {
  if(!e) return;

  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet()
  var sourcecell = book.getActiveCell();

//check the edited cell is a valid source cell

??  var sourcecelladdress = right(getA1Notation(sourcecell),2)  // need to get result such as: 'A1" or 'B1'...
  if ('B2C2D2B8C8D8'.indexOf(sourcecelladress) =-1) return;

// check the cell has actually been modified
  if (e.value = e.oldValue) return; 

//OK, so we're in a valid source cell, and it HAS been modified
// now let's build the formula string

  var sourcevalue = sourcecell.getValue()
  var enddate = sourcevalue/24 + now()
  var enddateday = int (endate) * 24
  var endatetime = hour (enddate)
??  var countdownformula = '=' + (enddateday + enddatehour) + '- (int(now())*24) - hour(now())'


//and now let's put it in the destination cell

??  var destcell = sourcecell + ????? (one row down from active cell)
??  destcell.setformula(countdownformula)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not optimized, effiecient, or necessarily the best way to handle it. The following demonstrates a couple of features you have stated wanting, and suggests multiple ways of solving the problem.

```
function onEdit(e){
  // if we did not receive the event data, it is likely 
  // no event occured. This should only happen if we 
  // call it directly.
  // So... if (no event object) get out;
  if(!e) return;


  // Look up the spreadsheet and and actual 
  // sheet we are goign to be interacting with
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getSheetByName('Sheet1')

  // get the "Working Range" of cells
  var range = book.getRange('B2');

  // determine if its the range we are interested in
  var target = range.getA1Notation();
  var change = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if(range.getA1Notation() == e.range.getA1Notation()){

    // double check that the value actually changed
    if(e.value != e.oldValue){
      // IT CHANGED!!
      book.toast('Timer setting change detected: ' + e.oldValue + ' -> ' + e.value);

      // Change some formulas using relative notiation
      range = book.getRange('B4');
      range.setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
      range.setValues(range.getValues());

      // Apply the future time to a formula in the spreadsheet
      range = book.getRange('B5');
      range.setFormula('=floor((B4-now())*24)');
      // copy and paste the value calculated by the formula
      range.setValue(range.getValue());

      //** Hardcoded alternative
      //** I would actually suggest not doing i this way and instead just hiding row 4

      // Calculate future time 
      // (this is broken because date math is annoying)
      var future = new Date(); // get NOW
      future.setHours(future.getHours() + e.value); //Add the specified hours to the current hours
      future = (future.getTime() / 86400000.0); // convert the time to fractional days
      future = future + 25569; //adjust the days for different start epochs

      // set the formula
      range = book.getRange('B6');
      range.setFormula('=floor((' + future + '-now())*24)');
    }
  }
}
```

I know at least the B6 calculation is incorrect, though *almost* right. I leave it as an excersize to the reader to fix the date math portion.

GoogleAppsScript uses javascript as it's underlying language, with a few custom libraries for handling various custom things (like spreadsheets).

Some references you may find useful:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Ok thanks, that helps.
I need to do it in 3 steps
1- set global on-edit trigger, and check that the active cell is within the list of input cells (hard-coded list) and that it has been changed; if not exit
2a- build the destination cell's address (one row down from current)
2b- build the destination cell's formula as a text string
3- paste that formula. Dang that syntax is totally foreign to me

Comment: I've updated the answer with the references I used to build the sample, as well as updated the comments to (hopefully) explain the code a little better. Your comments and the code are similar (enough). The code does work, though some of it is redundant (I did things twice to demonstrate two different ways of achieving the same thing). Depending on how you want the process to flow, you may need further functions, I tried to pack all the functionality into a single function.